# What is the value of the given resistor?

Tags: resistors, resistance

[image: resistor from a stepper motor driver of 6A 20-50vDC]

I tried checking with 5 band color code but was unsuccessful.
Resistor is blown hence the value cannot be determined using multimeter.

Comment: Are you sure it is blown?  It could be an inductor.  In any case, you can't usually measure resistors in circuit.

Comment: @JRE the one i shared is the working one    yes the resistor is blown and i cannot measure the value and have no working drivers

Comment: Although you managed to hide the component designator, it _does_ look like it says `Rxx`, but it would be nicer if you could clarify that. It looks more like a fuse.

Comment: @pipe it is R25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fusible metal film resistor which has value of 5.8 ohms with +/- 0.5% tolerance.[Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://store.comet.bg/download-file.php%3Fid%3D411&ved=2ahUKEwjY9pnH_7jgAhVMMo8KHdszBJIQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw1GnxOEv2Ig_3Cz7kcqk0t5)

Comment: The third band is grey!

Comment: why is there a huge gap between 3rd band and 4th band? thanks for the reference

Comment: It's probably just  another way of color coding..

Comment: If my answer works for you please accept it by clicking on the tick mark

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if third band is white or gray. 5.8 ohm ±0.5% tolerance.

Comment: for white : 5.9 ohm +- 0.5 tolerance.

Comment: Third band looks silver to me.

Comment: silver and gold can be used as multiplier only!

Comment: Third band looks silver to me i have calculated the same 5ohms value but i am not certain

Comment: yes third band looks silver the band color coding is confusing my best guess is 5ohms 2w resistor but maybe someone who  has more knowledge can help

Answer (score 0):

This circuit looks somewhat familiar, and I believe it is both a resistor and a fuse, the thin metal at higher voltage will 'blow' the resistor but at lower voltage regulates the current, so a surge current (or rouge failure of the power circuit) won't kill the rest of the components.

Comment: I'm confused can you add more information?